# date format when plotting a time series in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series, prediction

My data frame `df` is a daily time series with `Datum` and `Opbrengst` variables. The `Datum` variable is between `20160101` to `20170521`.

```
      Datum  Opbrengst
1   20160101  40609276
2   20160102  79381098
3   20160103 114653269
4   20160104 126044535
5   20160105 180472785
...
```

I want to do the prediction, so the first thing I do is plot the series to see if the series is stationary or not (if it has seasonality).

However, the date variable is `numeric`, so when I plot the series,

```
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Datum , y=Opbrengst, group=1)) +
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()
```

it becomes like this:

[image: graph]

The problem is that the series crosses years, that's why R just treats it as a `numeric series`, not `time series`.

I tried to convert it to dates by using the method from [this website](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

```
 df$Datum = as.Date(df$Datum)
```

but the result is incorrect:

```
 "57166-06-26" "57166-06-27" "57166-06-28" "57166-06-29" "57166-06-30" "57166-07-01"
```

My questions are:

1. How do I change the datum variable to the date format so that I won't have a problem when I plot the graph? Because later I will do need to do both `daily` and `weekly` predictions.
2. I know if I use `plot.ts()`, then I don't need to change the time format. Can I also do the time series plot in `ggplot`?

[edit]

This is the a sample of the data:

```
df <- structure(list(Datum = 20160101:20160120, Opbrengst = c(40609276, 
79381098, 114653269, 126044535, 180472785, 169286880, 149272135, 
133645566, 70171285, 150029065, 149172032, 107843808, 138196732, 
136460905, 133595660, 61716435, 137309503, 193201850, 140766980, 
129859068)), .Names = c("Datum", "Opbrengst"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you use dput() to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Try `as.Date.character(df$Datum, format = "%Y %M %d")`

Comment: @SBista `as.Date.character(df$Datum, format = "%Y %M %d")` returns _wrong dates_, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299831/3817004)

Comment: @UweBlock sorry, my bad. I meant `as.Date.character(Datum, "%Y %m %d")`. Note that it is `%m` instead of `%M`. I guess there is no `%M` for dates `%m`  refers to `month (00-12)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the conversion of `df$Datum` to class `Date`. It has nothing to do with `ggplot2`

Creating sample data as `integer` including New Year:

```
(Datum <- c(20151224:20151231, 20160101:20160107))
 [1] 20151224 20151225 20151226 20151227 20151228 20151229 20151230 20151231 20160101
[10] 20160102 20160103 20160104 20160105 20160106 20160107
```

`anytime::anydate()` and `lubridate::ymd()` seem to be able to convert integer `Datum` directly without coercion to `character`.

```
anytime::anydate(Datum)
# [1] "2015-12-24" "2015-12-25" "2015-12-26" "2015-12-27" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-29"
# [7] "2015-12-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
#[13] "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06" "2016-01-07"

lubridate::ymd(Datum)
# [1] "2015-12-24" "2015-12-25" "2015-12-26" "2015-12-27" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-29"
# [7] "2015-12-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
#[13] "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06" "2016-01-07"
```

`as.Date()` throws errors here:

```
as.Date(Datum)
#Error in as.Date.numeric(Datum) : 'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(Datum, "%Y%m%d")
#Error in charToDate(x) : 
#  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

`Datum` needs to be coerced to `character` first:

```
as.Date(as.character(Datum), "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "2015-12-24" "2015-12-25" "2015-12-26" "2015-12-27" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-29"
# [7] "2015-12-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
#[13] "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06" "2016-01-07"
```

Note that the format string is `"%Y%m%d"` with a lowercase `m` *not* `"%Y%M%d"` with a capital `M`. Interestingly, `"%Y %m %d"` with blanks interspersed seems to be working as well, here.

---

#### Full example

```
# create data
df <- data.frame(
  Datum = c(20151220:20151231, 20160101:20160108),
  Opbrengst = c(40609276, 79381098, 114653269, 126044535, 180472785, 169286880, 
                149272135, 133645566, 70171285, 150029065, 149172032, 107843808, 
                138196732, 136460905, 133595660, 61716435, 137309503, 193201850, 
                140766980, 129859068))

# coerce to class Date
df$Datum <- anytime::anydate(df$Datum)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Datum, Opbrengst)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Note that the gap over New Year has gone.

Comment: @Sheryl I've used the double colon operator `::` to tell R  from which package a specific function has to be used. No need to load `library(anytime)`, then. This avoids cluttering the namespace with a bunch of loaded packages and avoids name conflicts which may result. In programming, it improves maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**

Changed `%M` to `%m`

There are many ways to do this. Three easy ones:

```
df <- structure(list(Datum = 20160101:20160120, Opbrengst = c(40609276, 79381098, 114653269, 126044535, 180472785, 169286880, 149272135, 133645566, 70171285, 150029065, 149172032, 107843808, 138196732, 136460905, 133595660, 61716435, 137309503, 193201850, 140766980, 129859068)), .Names = c("Datum", "Opbrengst"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

# 1. Using the as.Date function (as sugges5ted by @SBista) to create a date object: 
df$Datum <- as.Date.character(df$Datum, format = "%Y %m %d")

# 2. Or create a POSIXct object:
# df$Datum <- strptime(df$Datum, format = "%Y %m %d")  

# 3. Using 'lubridate' to create a Date or POSIXct object (see 'tz' argument in ?ymd):
# df$Datum <- lubridate::ymd(df$Datum, tz = NULL)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Datum , y=Opbrengst)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

Results in:

[image]

The problem with your example is that you weren't providing the 'format' argument, so R didn't know that it was year-month-day.

Comment: thanks, @raistlin! I've chosen #1 and #3 method you proposed, but my graph still looks like the same. I checked `df` and indeed the Datum has become date format.

Comment: can you paste the result of `dput(df)` on your original answer to get an idea of what the data looks like?

Comment: The output is truncated--I assume you have many observations. You could dput only the first 20 rows: `dput(df[1:20,])` Also, it's better if you dput the original `df`.

Comment: I re-edited it with `dput(df[1:20,])` and updated the result.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No. My dataset is a daily data from `20160101` to `20170521`. From `20161231 to 20170101`, R doesn't know that is time, so I have a discontinuous graph like above. I used `df$Datum <- as.Date.character(df$Datum, format = "%Y %M %d")
` to change the time format and plot the ggplot `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Datum , y=Opbrengst)) +
        geom_line()+
        geom_point()`, the graph is still the same.

Comment: The given dates `20160101:20160120` seem to denote dates in January 2016 but in the chart May 2016 is plotted. Something is going wrong here.

Comment: @UweBlock, it was because I present the first 20 rows data `dput(df[1:20,])`. but the full data is from `20160101 to 20170521`

Comment: No, the problem was the wrong format string `"%Y %M %d"` which should read `"%Y %m %d"` (lowercase `m`). `%M` is for minutes, `%m` is for months.